# Minimize $ \arg \min_{A} {\| A x - b \|}_{2} $ (Least Squares Minimization on the Matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, regression, machine-learning

I have a machine learning regression problem. I need to minimize

$$\sum_i \|Ax_i-b_i\|_2^2$$

However I am trying to find matrix $A$, not the usual $x$, and I have lots of example data for $x_i$ and $b_i$. In general $A$ has more rows than columns.

Additionally I would like a solution for minimizing the Mahalanobis distance version, where $C$ is the SPSD covariance matrix:

$$\sum_i(Ax_i-b_i)^TC^{-1}(Ax_i-b_i)$$

I'm thinking that my problem can be re-written into the usual least squares problem but not sure if I am doing it correctly.

Comment: Did you mean $\|Ax_i-b_i\|^2$, or are you trying to minimize the L1 norm?

Comment: What norm are you using on the 'inside'? Is $C$ symmetric positive-definite?

Comment: I corrected the text to clarify the L2 norm.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Expanding the sum we get

$$\begin{align*}\sum_i \|Ax_i-b_i\|^2 &= \sum_i \sum_j (Ax_i-b_i)_j^2\\
&= \sum_i \sum_j \left(\sum_k A_{jk}x_{ki} - b_{ji}\right)^2\\
&= \sum_i \sum_j \left(\sum_k x^T_{ik} A^T_{kj} - b^T_{ij}\right)^2\\
&= \sum_i \sum_j (x^T A^T_j - b^T_j)_i^2\\
&= \sum_j \|x^T A^T_j - b_j^T\|^2.
\end{align*}$$

So you can solve the problem using regular least squares; your matrix $x^T$ has rows equal to your original known vectors $x_i$, the unknown vector $A_j^T$ is the $j$th row of $A$, and $b_1^T$ is the vector containing all of the first entries of the $b_i$, etc.

Comment: The OP asks to minimize the L1 norm.

Comment: Fair point; I assumed that was a typo since linear regression is usually done with least squares. I'll ask for clarification.

Comment: Sorry about that it is supposed to be the L2 norm.

Answer (score 3):

For the second problem, note $$\frac{\rm d}{\rm{d} A}((Ax-b)^TC^{-1}(Ax-b))=-2xb^T{C^{-1}}^T+{C^{-1}}^TAxx^T+C^{-1}Axx^T$$
so if $C^{-1}$ is symmetric (hence $C$ is also symmetric), we have the normal equation for $\sum_i(Ax_i-b_i)^TC^{-1}(Ax_i-b_i)$
$$\sum_iAx_ix_i^T=\sum_iCx_ib_i^TC^{-1}$$
or
$$\sum_ix_ix_i^TA^T=\sum_iC^{-1}b_ix_i^TC$$

So $A$ can be computed row by row, and let $a_j$ be the $j$-th column of $A^T$ ($j$-th row of $A$) and $d_j$ be the $j$-th column of $\sum_iC^{-1}b_ix_i^TC$, thus $a_j$ can be computed by solving $$\sum_ix_ix_i^Ta_j=d_j$$

Comment: OK thats helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you're really interested in the $L^1$ norm, then this is computationally nontrivial. Luckily there have been many recent advances in the last 10 years. Look at the key 2005 paper by Nesterov, [Smooth minimization of nonsmooth functions](http://luthuli.cs.uiuc.edu/~daf/courses/Optimization/MRFpapers/nesterov05.pdf).

Another competitive method is Bregman $L^1$ optimization, but I don't know very much about it.

Comment: This is useful but I did intend the L2 norm, which is consistent with the second matrix equation.